# php Github Gist API create array content is not a string

Tags: php, arrays, github-api, gist

everybody,

I use the following API: https://github.com/akshay9/PHP-gist-API

My script looks like this:

```php
include_once('includes/gist_api.php');
$gistAPI = new gistAPI('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

function create_githubgist($text, $title, $public = false) {

    global $gistAPI;

$filesArray = array("file1.txt" => array("content" => "Some Random Content"));

    $newGist = $gistAPI->createGist($filesArray, 'Create by TEST', $public);

    return $newGist;

}

$image_githubgist = create_githubgist('tEST', 'testtest', false);


/*var_dump($image_githubgist);*/

echo '<pre>' . var_export($image_githubgist, true) . '</pre>';
```

When I run the script, I get the following message:

> ```
> 'message' => 'Invalid request.
> ```
>
> For \'properties/content\', {"content"=>"Some Random Content"} is not a string.',
>       'documentation_url' => 'https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist',

I'd appreciate any help.

**EDIT MYSELF:**
I was able to correct it myself:
https://github.com/BennyChange/PHP-gist-API

Comment: If you've followed the documentation of the library you're using and it still doesn't work, you should contact the developers (add an issue on their gtihub). SO is for when you're having issues with _your_ code. We're not here to help you debug someone else's code.

Comment: Oh. I see that you've already created an issue on their github. Then you should wait for their response instead of posting it here as well.

Comment: This library isn't updated in 5 years, it probably been deprecated. Try finding a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find an alternative. I only want to be able to create, edit and delete Gists. Since there is no composer installed on my webspace, I can't use any other API. :/

Comment: I was able to correct it myself:
https://github.com/BennyChange/PHP-gist-API